# Run .exe file in gwt client side

Tags: gwt

In gwt client is there any way to download exe file from server and run that exe in gwt client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No.

At least it is not specific for GWT in comparision with other Javascript ways to do this. That is: If there is a way to do this then it is a huge bug and security flaw in the browser. You would read about this all over in the computer press, it would be fixed by the browser vendors within hours (hopefully).

You can offer the file for download and let the user execute it. But I suspect that is not what you want, specifically it is not running in the context of the GWT code on client side.